# Resolving Lucene Index error

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Why do I get error like this in Lucene and how to resolve it?

Could not find file 'C:\Indexes_z3_1.del'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a corrupt index.

**If** the index can easily be rebuilt from another datasource, the simplest thing to do would be to delete it and rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.But may I know why does the index get corrupted at the first place?

Comment: How are you currently building and updating your index?

Comment: Ed, While creating the index, if IndexWriter is not closed cleanly, you will end up with corrupt index.

Comment: @Ed, you can try using Luke: http://www.getopt.org/luke/
to view the index. It may give you additional information about why the index is corrupt.